# Как создать дизайн сайта back-end разработчику

Tags: asp.net, frontend

В общем я сделал внутреннюю часть сайта(логику и практически весь back-end) 
на Asp Core 2.1.
Но по часть дизайна сайта я полный профан. 
Подскажите что мне делать. Что и какие инструменты например используют full stack developer-ы в связке с Asp Core? Что лучше а что нет(или что проще)?

Посредственно знаю html/css, js немного хуже.

Comment: Пожалуй как обычно самый простой вариант использовать [бутстрап](https://getbootstrap.com/) ну или [uikit](https://getuikit.com/) (мне он больше симпотизирует)

Comment: А в front-end-е нету возможности как в wpf или winforms? То есть создавать элементы с помощью какого-то редактора?

Comment: ну бутстрап в целом почти это и есть, набор готовых компонентов и в целом достаточно просто копипастить с [документации](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/alerts/)

Comment: @JuniorOne, как в wpf и winforms умеет делать asp.net webforms. Он был создан именно для таких разработчиков, как Вы. Но его считают устаревшим и (если я не ошибаюсь) его даже не портирвали в .NET Core. Так что лучше используйте Bootstrap